# Update Lambda function to use latest layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a fairly simple GitHub action that deploys my Lambda functions in addition to updating the layers that they use. However after doing so, the functions continue to use the old version of the layer. I have to go in to the console and manually update the functions to use the new layers.

Is there any way to do this via the cli or similar?

I know it's possible to specify a layer and version for a function with that, but I can't see a way to automatically set it to the latest version of the layer.

Here's my current action for deployment, for reference - https://github.com/Jademalo/JadeBots/blob/aws-lambda/.github/workflows/lambda-deploy.yml

Comment: There is no way to do that. You have to manually (i.e. using API) get the number of latest version and update your function accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that's surprising. I won't lie in saying I've got no idea how to do that with the API, especially in the context of a github action.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/CallumMackenzie/latest-lambda-layer-action, I will also try to deply the layers first and then deploy the functions. Also the layers can be added in the lambda deployment actions itself